# Show that $ x\in E: f(x)>g(x)$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm studying for my exam that's coming up in a few days and I've run into this problem in the textbook by Manfred Stoll regarding continuous functions.

Suppose $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g: E \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous on $E$. Show that $ ({x\in E: f(x)>g(x)})$ is open in $E$.

I began by letting $p(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ which is always $>0$ (which is stated). Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, $p(x)$ is also a continuous function. Then there's a theorem stating:

*If $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and if $f:K\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $K$, then $f(K)$ is compact.*

The question is posed to show that the reverse of the theorem is not true. Since on the real axis, compactness is equivalent to closed and bounded, I think that I only need to show that $f(x)>g(x)$ is not bounded, which makes it open.

Comment: $\{x\in X | f(x)>g(x)\}=p^{-1} (\mathbb{R}^+)$. Since $p$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}^+$. Therefore $p^{-1} (\mathbb{R}>0)$ is open.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $h=f-g$ which's continuous so what we can say for
$$h^{-1}(]0,+\infty[)?$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**(Different approach): If you are asked to show that a set is open ,you can do it straightforward or you can show that it's complement is closed.Same for the case that you have to show that a set is closed.

Let $A=${$x\in E:f(x)> g(x)$}

Then $A^{c}=${$x\in E:f(x)\geq g(x)$}. So, if $(x_n)\subset A^{c}$ a sequence such that $x_n\to x$ then $f(x_n)\geq g(x_n)$ for every $n$ and due to continuity $g(x_n)\to g(x)\leq f(x)$ where $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ and thus $x\in A^{c}$ which means that $A^{c}$ is closed which means that $A$ is open.

Comment: @user108831 ,check my proof please.thank you